# In "Star vs the Forces of Evil" was there ever a canonical explanation why the wand took on a sinister appearance when Marco held it?

Tags: star-vs-the-forces-of-evil

In the Disney XD show *Star vs the Forces of Evil*, was there ever a canonical explanation given in the show or the expanded universe material as to why the magic wand took on a dark and sinister appearance when Marco held it?